# Calling 3rd party native library in your own android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, java-native-interface

Is it possible to write code for native libraries you do not have the source code for in your own android app?

For example - [RarLab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar)'s android app comes with a native library `librarlab_rar.so` for at least 4 different platforms.

Assuming that I'm doing this for experimental and copyright isn't an issue and I don't plan to distribute the app externally, is it possible to compile a Java/Kotlin android-based app with only including the native binary in android development tools such as Android Studio or Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to disassemble the binary `.so` file and work out the API yourself. This process is called **reverse engineering**.

See: [How do I reverse engineer .so files found in android APKs?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4624/11705) for ideas on how to accomplish the task.

Once you've figured out how to call into the `.so` file, you can then write your own version of the API which you can then call from Java/Kotlin.

Comment: But typically Android Studio is configured to compile native source code, that is the C part. If you are just throwing in a native library, how do you specify it on the path?

Comment: You can include third-party libraries: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

Comment: You can add the path to your cmakes file and it'll grab it and have it's way with it.

Answer (score 0):

Any `lib….so` file that you put under `jniLibs/$(ABI)` folder in your app will automatically get packed to APK and unpacked to the device (provided the **ABI** matches). You may need to write your own Java wrapper for the libraries, or to reuse the Java classes that you need from the same app.